# Trying to use a bubble sort to sort a string array alphabetically but sort is returning the reverse of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm currently trying to read from a .txt file into a string array and then use a bubble sort to sort them alphabetically though when I actually run my code it gives the reverse of my array as seen below:

```
bool swapped = true;
int j = 0;
string tmp;

while (swapped)
{
    swapped = false;
        j++;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].compare(arr[i + 1]));
        {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout <<arr[i + 1];
}
```

This is the code for the bubble sort.

```
ifstream file("titles.txt");

string myArray[6];


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {

        file >> myArray[i];
        //cout << myArray[i];


    }

    sortStrings(myArray, 6);
```

and this is the code for the reading of the .txt file.

the file contains the letters b c a d e f in this order
though the output i receive is edabc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your display loop doesn't print the first element in the array. And will index the array out of bounds.

Comment: What does `if (arr[i].compare(arr[i + 1]));` do?   *This is a common newbie mistake!*  (There shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of that line.)

Comment: Regarding that call to the [`compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) function. It doesn't return a boolean value, but a value that indicates the *relative* difference between the strings. You need to compare the returned result of `compare` to `0` (less than or greater than).

Comment: Lastly, please note that both the problem with the extra semicolon and the comparison result should have been possible to figure out if you tried to *debug* your program. Problems like this is typically solved by stepping through the code statement by statement in a debugger. Knowing how to use a debugger and other debugging techniques is crucial for any type of programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a few problems and this should work:

```
bool swapped = true;
string tmp;
int j = 0;

while (swapped)
{
    swapped = false;
    ++j;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++)
    {
        // 1. Your original code has a comma in the following line which terminates the if statement
        // 2. compare function returns signed integer indicating the relationship 
        // between two strings, and > 0 value indicates previous string is greater:
        //    http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/
        if (arr[i].compare(arr[i + 1]) > 0) 
        {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = tmp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout <<arr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon at the end of an if statement works as if the condition is always true.
The following snippets are identical

```cpp
if (cond);
{
   // ...
}
```

```cpp
if (cond) { }
// ...
```

Take a look `std::string`'s [compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) method:

> **Return value**
>
> negative value if `*this` appears before the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order
>
> zero if both character sequences compare equivalent
>
> positive value if `*this` appears after the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order

Thus, you should rather check if the value greater than zero in order to sort in ascending order. There is also [operator >](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) for `std::string`, that wouldn't result in the error you encountered.

Summary (formatting applied):

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sortStrings(string* arr, int n) {
  bool swapped = true;
  int j = 0;
  string tmp;

  while (swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    j++;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) {
      if (arr[i].compare(arr[i + 1]) > 0) {
        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = tmp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  ifstream file("titles.txt");

  string myArray[6];

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    file >> myArray[i];
  }

  sortStrings(myArray, 6);
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cout << myArray[i] << ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!